# IntelliJ IDEA зависает на строке WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Tags: java, selenium

При запуске, проект зависает (более 10 минут, прерывал каждый раз) на строке:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

При использовании `HtmlUnitDriver` такого не происходит.

Как работать с `FirefoxDriver()`?

IntelliJ IDEA  2016.1.2
Build #IC-145.972, built on May 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Comment: Понаблюдайте за памятью. Запустить FF это очень накладно.

Comment: После установки дополнения WebDriver в браузер FireFox длительное зависание исчезло, но появилась следующая ошибка:

    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
    Build info: version: '2.8.0', revision: '14056', time: '2011-10-06 15:53:48'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После установки установки свежих версий selenium 2.53.0 и браузера Firefox версии 46.0.1 (Настройки сборки Firefox от Яндекс, yandex - 1.2) проблема устранилась, всё заработало.

Аналогичное повторение ошибок произошло и на Ubuntu 14. После обновления selenium до 2.53.0 ошибка ушла.

Дополнение: Важна именно связка версий selenium 2.53.0 и Firefox 46.0.1